# Need help with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-tables

I have a table of songs, some songs are album song, and some are singles...
And I have a table of albums...

Example:

if the album ID is [null], it means the song is a single

Songs Table:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+----------------+---------+---------------+-------+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+----------+
| Row ID | Song ID | Album ID  |    Song Name   |   Band  | Date Released | Genre | Lyrics | Lenght | Size | Plays | Likes | Dislikes |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------------+---------+---------------+-------+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+----------+
|    1   | Song-01 |  Album-1  |    Song-001    | Band-1  |  2010-12-15   | Rock  |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |  101  |  11   |    1     |
|    2   | Song-02 |  Album-1  |    Song-002    | Band-1  |  2010-12-15   | Rock  |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |  102  |  12   |    2     |
|    3   | Song-03 |  Album-1  |    Song-003    | Band-1  |  2010-12-15   | Rock  |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |  103  |  13   |    3     |
|    4   | Song-04 |   [null]  |    Song-004    | Band-1  |  2010-12-16   | Rock  |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |  104  |  14   |    4     |
|    5   | Song-05 |  Album-2  |    Song-005    | Band-1  |  2010-12-17   | POP   |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |  105  |  15   |    5     |
|    6   | Song-06 |  Album-2  |    Song-006    | Band-1  |  2010-12-17   | RAP   |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |  106  |  16   |    6     |
|    7   | Song-07 |   [null]  |    Song-007    | Band-2  |  2010-12-17   | Rock  |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |  107  |  17   |    7     |
|    8   | Song-08 |  Album-3  |    Song-008    | Band-2  |  2010-12-17   | Rock  |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |  108  |  18   |    8     |
|    9   | Song-09 |  Album-3  |    Song-009    | Band-2  |  2010-12-17   | POP   |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |  109  |  19   |    9     |
|   10   | Song-10 |  Album-3  |    Song-010    | Band-2  |  2010-12-17   | Punk  |   ...  |  6:30  | 6 MB |  110  |  20   |    0     |
|   11   | Song-11 |  Album-3  |    Song-011    | Band-2  |  2010-12-17   | RAP   |   ...  |  7:30  | 7 MB |  111  |  21   |    1     |
|   12   | Song-12 |   [null]  |    Song-012    | Band-2  |  2010-12-18   | Rock  |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |  112  |  22   |    2     |
|   13   | Song-13 |   [null]  |    Song-013    | Band-2  |  2010-12-18   | Rock  |   ...  |  2:30  | 2 MB |  113  |  23   |    3     |
|   14   | Song-14 |   [null]  |    Song-014    | Band-3  |  2010-12-18   | Rock  |   ...  |  6:30  | 6 MB |  114  |  24   |    4     |
|   15   | Song-15 |   [null]  |    Song-015    | Band-3  |  2010-12-19   | Rock  |   ...  |  7:30  | 7 MB |  115  |  25   |    5     |
|   16   | Song-16 |   [null]  |    Song-016    | Band-3  |  2010-12-19   | Rock  |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |  116  |  26   |    6     |
|   17   | Song-17 |   [null]  |    Song-017    | Band-4  |  2010-12-19   | POP   |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |  117  |  27   |    7     |
|   18   | Song-18 |   [null]  |    Song-018    | Band-4  |  2010-12-19   | POP   |   ...  |  2:30  | 2 MB |  118  |  28   |    8     |
|   19   | Song-19 |   [null]  |    Song-019    | Band-5  |  2010-12-20   | Rock  |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |  119  |  29   |    9     |
|   20   | Song-20 |   [null]  |    Song-020    | Band-5  |  2010-12-20   | Rock  |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |  120  |  30   |    0     |
|   21   | Song-21 |   [null]  |    Song-021    | Band-5  |  2010-12-20   | Rock  |   ...  |  6:30  | 6 MB |  121  |  31   |    1     |
|   22   | Song-22 |  Album-4  |    Song-022    | Band-5  |  2010-12-21   | Rock  |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |  122  |  32   |    2     |
|   23   | Song-23 |  Album-4  |    Song-023    | Band-5  |  2010-12-21   | Rock  |   ...  |  2:30  | 2 MB |  123  |  33   |    3     |
|   24   | Song-24 |  Album-4  |    Song-024    | Band-5  |  2010-12-21   | Rock  |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |  124  |  34   |    4     |
|   25   | Song-25 |   [null]  |    Song-025    | Band-6  |  2010-12-22   | Rock  |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |  125  |  35   |    5     |
|   26   | Song-26 |   [null]  |    Song-026    | Band-6  |  2010-12-22   | Rock  |   ...  |  6:30  | 6 MB |  126  |  36   |    6     |
|   27   | Song-27 |  Album-5  |    Song-027    | Band-7  |  2010-12-22   | POP   |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |  127  |  37   |    7     |
|   28   | Song-28 |  Album-5  |    Song-028    | Band-7  |  2010-12-22   | PUNK  |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |  128  |  38   |    8     |
|   29   | Song-29 |   [null]  |    Song-029    | Band-7  |  2010-12-23   | Rock  |   ...  |  2:30  | 2 MB |  129  |  39   |    9     |
|   30   | Song-30 |  Album-6  |    Song-030    | Band-8  |  2010-12-25   | Rock  |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |  130  |  40   |    0     |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------------+---------+---------------+-------+--------+--------+------+-------+-------+----------+
```

Albums Table:

```
+--------+-----------+----------------+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+-------+----------+
| Row ID | Album ID  |    Album Name  |   Band  | Date Released |       Genre       | Lenght | Likes | Dislikes |
+--------+-----------+----------------+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+-------+----------+
|    1   |  Album-1  |    Album One   | Band-1  |  2010-12-15   |       Rock        | 13:30  |  101  |    31    |
|    2   |  Album-2  |    Album Two   | Band-1  |  2010-12-17   |      POP/RAP      |  9:00  |  102  |    32    |
|    3   |  Album-3  |   Album Three  | Band-2  |  2010-12-17   | Rock/Punk/POP/RAP | 24:00  |  103  |    33    |
|    4   |  Album-4  |    Album Four  | Band-5  |  2010-12-21   |       Rock        | 10:30  |  104  |    34    |
|    5   |  Album-5  |    Album Five  | Band-7  |  2010-12-22   |      Punk/POP     |  8:00  |  105  |    35    |
|    6   |  Album-6  |    Album Six   | Band-8  |  2010-12-25   |       Rock        |  5:30  |  106  |    36    |
+--------+-----------+----------------+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+-------+----------+
```

And If I want to take only the latest five albums and/or singles
which means the result will be (ordered from latest to eldest):

by the column 'name' I mean 'Single name or Album name'

Page 1:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|       Name      |   Band  |  Date Released  |       Genre       | IsAlbum? | IsSingle? | Lyrics | Lenght | Size | Likes | Dislikes | Plays |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|  Album Six      | Band-8  |    2010-12-25   |       Rock        |   YES    |     NO    |    -   |  5:30  |  --  |  106  |    36    |   -   |
|  Song 29        | Band-7  |    2010-12-23   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  2:30  | 2 MB |   39  |     9    |  129  |
|  Album Five     | Band-7  |    2010-12-22   |      Punk/POP     |   YES    |     NO    |    -   |  8:00  |  --  |  105  |    35    |   -   |
|  Song 26        | Band-6  |    2010-12-22   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  6:30  | 6 MB |   36  |     6    |  126  |
|  song 25        | Band-6  |    2010-12-22   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |   35  |     5    |  125  |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

And If I want to take only the latest five after the latest five (the ones in the table above) albums and/or singles, the result will be  ordered from latest to eldest):

Page 2:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|       Name      |   Band  |  Date Released  |       Genre       | IsAlbum? | IsSingle? | Lyrics | Lenght | Size | Likes | Dislikes | Plays |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|  Album Four     | Band-5  |    2010-12-21   |       Rock        |   YES    |     NO    |    -   | 10:30  |  --  |  104  |    34    |   -   |
|  Song 21        | Band-5  |    2010-12-20   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  6:30  | 6 MB |   31  |     1    |  121  |
|  Song 20        | Band-5  |    2010-12-20   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |   30  |     0    |  120  |
|  Song 19        | Band-5  |    2010-12-20   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |   29  |     9    |  119  |
|  song 18        | Band-4  |    2010-12-19   |        POP        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  2:30  | 2 MB |   28  |     8    |  118  |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

And the five before them will be:

Page 3:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|       Name      |   Band  |  Date Released  |       Genre       | IsAlbum? | IsSingle? | Lyrics | Lenght | Size | Likes | Dislikes | Plays |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|  Song 17        | Band-4  |    2010-12-19   |        POP        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |   27  |     7    |  117  |
|  Song 16        | Band-3  |    2010-12-19   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |   26  |     6    |  116  |
|  Song 15        | Band-3  |    2010-12-19   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  5:30  | 5 MB |   25  |     5    |  115  |
|  Song 14        | Band-3  |    2010-12-18   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  6:30  | 6 MB |   24  |     4    |  114  |
|  song 13        | Band-2  |    2010-12-18   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  2:30  | 2 MB |   23  |     3    |  113  |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

And the five before:

Page 4:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|       Name      |   Band  |  Date Released  |       Genre       | IsAlbum? | IsSingle? | Lyrics | Lenght | Size | Likes | Dislikes | Plays |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|  Song 12        | Band-2  |    2010-12-18   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |   22  |     2    |  112  |
|  Album Three    | Band-2  |    2010-12-17   | Rock/Punk/POP/RAP |   YES    |     NO    |    -   | 24:00  |  --  |  103  |    33    |   -   |
|  Song 7         | Band-2  |    2010-12-17   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  3:30  | 3 MB |   17  |     7    |  107  |
|  Album Two      | Band-1  |    2010-12-17   |      POP/RAP      |   YES    |     NO    |    -   |  9:00  |  --  |  102  |    32    |   -   |
|  song 4         | Band-1  |    2010-12-16   |       Rock        |    NO    |    YES    |   ...  |  4:30  | 4 MB |   14  |     4    |  104  |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

And in the last table (or page):

Page 5:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|       Name      |   Band  |  Date Released  |       Genre       | IsAlbum? | IsSingle? | Lyrics | Lenght | Size | Likes | Dislikes | Plays |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|  Album One      | Band-1  |    2010-12-15   |       Rock        |   YES    |     NO    |    -   | 13:00  |  --  |  101  |    31    |   -   |
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

But, the problem is that when I do that the X and the Y in "LIMIT X , Y" won't be X=0,Y=5 or X=5,Y=5 or X=10,Y=5 and so on...
Also, I need different columns from each table in the result (look at the examples)...

**So, my question is: how can I do what I did above in PHP and SQL (MySQL) ?**

---

*Sorry for my english* 
*and, thanks in advance*

Comment: @cweiske : my problem is to find a way to do that (doesn't matter if it's with SQL or PHP) but to get the right results as in the examples ...

Answer (score 1):

i'm thinking that it could be done with a query, and the php code will only display the info and execute the queries for the pagination

the query might be something like:

```
SELECT IF(Album_ID IS NULL,s.Song_Name,a.Album_Name) as name,IF(Album_ID IS NULL,s.Date_Released,a.Date_Released) as datereleased
FROM songs s LEFT JOIN albums a ON (s.Album_ID = a.Row_ID)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 DESC,1
LIMIT 0,5; /* for the first page */
```

the idea is to use the `IF()` function, whenever you have a conflict between the two tables (like displaying the song's name or the album's name) and the rest of the columns will have NULL as value, you could use php to change it (columns like "IsAlbum")

the rest is just php excecuting queries, displaying the results, having links to the next page, etc.

Good Luck

Comment: thanks, it worked, but these I don't understand: "**GROUP BY 1,2**" and "ORDER BY **2** DESC,**1**" ?
and if I wanted for the datereleased to be the first released song in the album, what should I change ?

Comment: on `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` instead of specifying the column's name you can put the column's number (in the order of your SELECT statement).
to get the date of the first released song use
`MIN(s.Date_Released)` instead of the `IF(Album_ID IS NULL,s.Date_Released,a.Date_Released)` and change your GROUP BY to `GROUP BY 1`.. i'm not really sure if this will work =P but give it a try

Comment: didn't work, but, thanks anyway :)